# Cargo build for Linux compilation errors from Once_cell?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, rust, rust-cargo

I have a cargo workspace project which I build and run on my Windows laptop. The program hosts a backend server. Now, I would like to host this on an AWS EC2 instance which is a Linux machine. What I thought I'd do is first cargo build for linux and then simply put the .exe into the ec2 instance and run it from there.

I tried two things (form my Windows machine):

i)
`cargo build --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` - this gives me some really strange compile errors , like
`` error[E0412]: cannot find type `Result` in this scope;  error: could not compile `once_cell` due to 223 previous errors ``

ii) Tried another target:
`cargo build --target=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu` And got pretty much same thing.

Is this some limitiation of once_cell? Or, much more likely, I am missing something fundamental here?

Comment: The `unknown-linux-gnu` targets attempt to link to the Linux `glibc`, which of course won't be possible on your Windows machine. You can try using the `musl` targets instead.

Comment: Thanks @PitaJ. `cargo build --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl` also throws `can't find crate for core`. Am I right understanding that I should not actually build for LInux from WIndows? If I want to build for Linux system, I should do it *from* Linux system?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/japaric/rust-cross and https://github.com/KodrAus/rust-cross-compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting indicates that the standard library can't be found. When cross-compiling from Windows to Linux, it's best to use `*-musl` targets, to avoid having to come up with the Linux-specific libraries that `*-gnu` targets require. To fix the errors simply run the following command:

```bash
rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
```

This will install the relevant stdlib. You will have to do this for each toolchain you intend to cross-compile from (if you want to use both stable and nightly or something).

If you `cargo build` at this point, and instead of getting a bunch of compiler errors, you should be getting linker errors instead. To fix this, add the following lines to your `.cargo/config.toml` file:

```ini
[target.x86_64-unknown-linux-musl]
linker = "rust-lld"
```

That should be enough to get things built, although some crates may have platform/toolchain requirements that might take some more effort to satisfy.

Of course, that assumes amazon's ec2 instances are actually x86_64 machines, which they may not be. Similar steps should work for other platforms, just using the required target. For example, to build for a 64-bit arm platform you would just use the same steps but with the target `aarch64-unknown-linux-musl`, and I use these steps with `armv7-unknown-linux-musleabihf` to build stuff for my raspberry pi.